# Create Zoho campaign with api

Tags: zoho

I tried to create a zoho campaign following this link
https://www.zoho.com/campaigns/help/api/create-campaign.html

but every time, I get an error.

This is the link that I used

https://campaigns.zoho.com/api/v2/createcampaign?campaignName=mynewone&from_email=sammoudi.maher@gmail.com&subject=testSubject&authtoken=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&resfmt=json

Where is the issue ?

Comment: Well - **what** is the error you're getting? Remember: we cannot read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to **SHOW US** all the relevant information for anyone to be able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

the url is case sensitive. I think the url you are using should be https://campaigns.zoho.com/api/v2/createCampaign? (note the capital "C" at the end)